# Incorrect value while debugging in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, debugging, variables, visual-studio-2015

Assume we have sample code (VS2015, WinForms, .Net 4.6.1):

```
List<int> items = new List<int>();
private async Task test(int id)
{
    id = 1;
    int id_real = id;

    int index = items.FindIndex(x => x == id);
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await test(0);
}
```

Now "the feature":
[image]

How is that possible? The interesting part - it is only Visual Studio watcher problem, runtime result remains correct.

For now I know it is only happens in VS2015, and cause of this behaviour - the last string in test method.

Comment: It works okay for me in VS2017... have you tried there? And what happens if you look at the Locals window instead of Watch?

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes I've tried also VS2013 and VS2017 - no issue in there. Locals window shows same result as watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging, and then re-debug your app, I think you would get the correct result in debugger windows as the VS2013 or VS2017.

[image]

Updated：

I also reported this issue to the connect report even if we could resolve this issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/3135000/incorrect-value-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. But I'm just curious why VS2013 and VS2017 working fine without enabling this option?

Comment: @Alek Depler, Glad to know that it resolved this issue, what I know that if we are debugging in VS2015 and we have built the app using an earlier debugging engine, this is the option to check. So if we enable that option which will force an older debugging engine to be used. But I also agree with you, it would be a feedback for VS2015 even if we find the workaround for this issue.

Comment: @Alek Depler, I help you report this issue to the product team. Of course, if the reply was helpful for you, please mark it as the answer. For that feedback, you could add your comment and vote it.